# Retrieve some part of video without using software. Is it possible?

Tags: c#, html, activex

I am working on a project which is related to videos.

I need to cut part of a video (I want to retrieve that part of video which lies from 00:30:00 to 00:40:00).
I have searched about it and found it can be done by using ffmpeg (This is a command line tool which is used to edit and convert videos.) But I don't want to use any tool.

Is it possible to do this with code, rather then with another tool?

Comment: Just chopping up the file based on the byte count won't work, you actually need a program that's able to correctly *read* the file and extract the stream from the start point and reencode it.  Likke ffmpeg does.

Comment: "Is it possible to do this with code and without any external software?" Probably. Depends on whether or not the video in question is encoded using an open standard.

Too bad the question was edited, I prepared a beautiful rant about how you could just draw the pictures with a pencil after manually de-encoding the video.

Comment: In good old times you could simply cut the tape with scissors and glue it back the way you like... Now you have to provide more details on what is your actual restriction and what you do want to use to perform the operation.

Comment: @RajputAdi Why did you use the c# tag to tag this question?  Are you looking for a solution that more or less does what ffmpeg does, but that's embeddable in a C# program?

Comment: "But I don't want to use any tool. Is it possible to do this with code, rather then with another tool?" -- If it can be done by using ffmpeg, then sure, as ffmpeg is also usable as a library rather than a command-line tool. And if you want code to put in your own executable, why not look at the ffmpeg source code?

Answer (score 0):

If what you actually want is to build the capability to cut samples out of existing video material into a .net program the [splicer](http://splicer.codeplex.com/) project might be what you're looking for.

Comment: Looks useful. I remember being recommended asfmojo when I wanted something to re-organize a video file; I found it fell short of what I wanted though.

Comment: I dont want to use any project or software.. i think it is mentioned in question also.

Comment: @RajputAdi as stated in the comments before, without using any software it's **not** possible - learn how videos are encoded (maybe start [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_of_pictures) and you'll understand why chopping up files (that is, cutting without actually decoding them - maybe partially with some formats) can never work.  What I propose here is a smallish open source project running on top of Windows' media framework.  You may want to clean up and clarify your question a bit as as it stands you mention c# and activex, both of which imply some programming.

Comment: @fvu - I don't think that there's any point in answering this. I for one still have no idea what the author is actually looking for. The code part was an edit by J.Evans, the original question was completely unintelligible and the author didn't really attempt to clear it up so far.

Comment: @cubic - What part of question u didn't understand? It is clear from the question i want to have part of video which lies between the given time,i don't want to use any software to cut that part and i want to do it with coding. If you have any clue about this then post it. I am newbie here and i dont think you were perfect and you have known every rule when you joined this site. Instead of criticising, you can ask question if you dont get anything related to question.